# Different behavior of Java System Property 'java.io.tmpdir'

Tags: java, operating-system

When i try to get String tempdir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
It will return me my Operating system 'temp' directory path. e.g. C:\Users\DATAGU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\   in normal java application. That's right.

But when i try to get the same property on my web application deployed on tomcat6
It is returning me the tomcat temp directory path(e.g. D:\tomcat6\temp). Can somebody know why this is happening?
Also is there any way to get the default OS temp direcotry path from my web application because i need to store some file in temp directory which should be the OS temp directory only.

I have also tried: 
File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-file", "tmp");            System.out.println("Temp file : " + temp.getAbsolutePath());

This method has a same behavior as of the above method.
Did anybody have any idea :) ?

Answer (score 0):

> The default temporary-file directory is specified by the system property java.io.tmpdir. On UNIX systems the default value of this property is typically "/tmp" or "/var/tmp"; on Microsoft Windows systems it is typically "C:\WINNT\TEMP". A different value may be given to this system property when the Java virtual machine is invoked, but programmatic changes to this property are not guaranteed to have any effect upon the temporary directory used by this method.

[From the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File))

Thus, Tomcat must be setting the `java.io.tmpdir` system property. If you really need a different value to be used, you'll have to provide it there.

Or just use the `File.createTempFile(String, String, File)` function (which I linked asaa the source above) to provide the directory. This would probably be more ideal since you wouldn't have to fight with Tomcat for who gets to set the system property.

Comment: Yeh Mike I agree with you to don't set the system property manually but File.createTempFile(String, String,null) method is also do the same- means it returns the tomcat temp directory path rather than the path i required(OS Path) because it could be different for both windows and linux machine. Also i do not want to set the File path manually in this method.